# How to get one record and get all the warnings of that record from DB using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables ,

records 
errors

in the records tables we are storing , json document and in the errors tables we store warnings and errors if any during the (business )validation of that json .

now i need to implement , like we need to send the record and warnings for that record if any present for the record in errors table.

when i written the query

```
SELECT records.record as record,errors.description as warning FROM records as records
  INNER JOIN  errors as errors
  ON records.track_num=errors.track_num
where records.lading_number='123456789'
```

for this query , am getting below type of result

```
record      warning
<<record>>  <<warning1>>
<<record>>  <<warning2>>
<<record>>  <<warning3>>
<<record>>  <<warning4>>
<<record>>  <<warning5>>
```

so here in the record column it is same json document , but in the warning column it lists all the warnings present for the record

this result is returning to application from the db , here i need is their anyway we can write sql query so that it will return only one instance of record and all the list of warnings if present. can any one please help.

```
Environment :
  spring boot
  postgres V10.5
```

Comment: Which database you have used?

Comment: @iamrajshah , we are using postgresV10.5

Comment: It seems you want to use GROUP BY clause, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than joining single warnings to the record, you want to join a block of warnings:

```
SELECT r.record, e.warnings 
FROM records r
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT track_num, STRING_AGG(description, '; ') AS warnings
  FROM errors
  GROUP BY track_num
) e ON e.track_num = r.track_num
where r.lading_number = 123456789;
```

This separates the warnings with a semicolon and a blank. Use `E'\r\n'`, if you want CR/LF instead. Or just any other separator.

An alternative to `STRING_AGG` is `ARRAY_AGG` provided your app can deal with it.

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, if you also want to show records that have no warnings.